# Unexpected behavior of smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to get the managed object of an aliased shared pointer. My idea was using a weak pointer. Since weak pointers doesn't yield any objects I thought creating a weak pointer from a shared pointer would make the weak pointer forget the stored object of the aliased shared pointer and hence locking the weak pointer would yield a shared pointer with the equal stored and managed pointers. But the results I got confuse me. Does the weak pointer remember from what share pointer is constructed? And is there a way how to get the managed object of an aliased shared pointer?

```
template<class T> struct Deleter {
    void operator()(T* p) const {};
};

Deleter<T> d {};
T t1 {};
T* p1 = &t1;
T t2 {};
T* p2 = &t2;
auto sp1 = std::shared_ptr<T>(p1,d);
auto sp2 = std::shared_ptr<T>(sp1,p2);
auto wp = std::weak_ptr<T>(sp2);
std::cout << sp1.get() << " " << sp2.get() << " " << wp.lock().get() << std::endl;
```

produce `0x7fff5798c958 0x7fff5798c948 0x7fff5798c948`

Comment: What's the question? What different output were you expecting?

Comment: I expected `0x7fff5798c958 0x7fff5798c948 0x7fff5798c958`

Comment: It would be very bad if `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` acted the way you expected. Aliasing `shared_ptr`s will not be as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the weak pointer remember from what share pointer is constructed?

It remembers the raw pointer which was stored by the `shared_ptr` from which it was constructed. I think it would be very confusing if things worked the way you are expecting. For example, if a function recieved a `shared_ptr<T>` as an argument, it has no idea whether it is aliasing or not. And if that function then wanted to take a `weak_ptr` from that `shared_ptr`, it would, I think, be very surprising behavior to find that actualizing that `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` gave a completely different object than the original `shared_ptr` from which it was obtained.

Also note that the aliasing `shared_ptr` can store a different type than the `shared_ptr` which it is aliasing. The types don't even have to be convertible to/from each other. And a `weak_ptr` which is constructed from an aliasing `shared_ptr` gets its stored type from the `shared_ptr` it was constructed from (or an implicitly convertible type).

The most common use case for an aliasing `shared_ptr`, I would suspect (even though I've never had need for one), would be to pass around a member of a shared object, and to be sure it stays alive even if the rest of the owned object is no longer needed. So the scenario which you've constructed, where the type of the aliasing `shared_ptr` is the same as the original, seems like it would be uncommon.

> And is there a way how to get the managed object of an aliased shared pointer?

As far as I'm aware, no. Perhaps there should be. If you think this feature would be useful, propose it. https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-proposals

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The scenario I presented was made up to trick an aliased shared pointer to yield its managed object. I was just surprised it lacks this functionality. But there may be good reasons for that.

Comment: @JiříLechner: I suspect the only reason it lacks that functionality is simply that nobody thought of it. And I suspect nobody thought of it because nobody needed it. If you do need it, flesh out your use case, and make a post on the forum I linked to at the bottom of my answer.